# in search giving false when expecting true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the below Python and expect the last item to prove true. I am searching for beer to see if it exists in the menu, but I am getting false. What am I missing here?

```
# [] print 3 tests, with description text, testing the menu variable for 'pizza', 'soup' and 'dessert'
menu = "salad, pasta, sandwich, pizza, drinks, dessert, soda, beer"
print("pizza is in the menu =", 'pizza' in menu)
print("soup is in the menu =", 'soup' in menu)
print("dessert is in the menu = ", 'dessert' in menu)
print("beer is in the menue = ", 'beer' in menu)

#now asking for a user to search an item
menu_ask = input("Type an item to see if it is in the menu: ")
print(menu_ask,"is in the menu = ", 'menu_ask'.lower() in menu.lower())
```

My output is as follows

```
pizza is in the menu = True
soup is in the menu = False
dessert is in the menu =  True
beer is in the menue =  True
Type an item to see if it is in the menu: beer
beer is in the menu =  False
```

Why is the last item not True? And how do I get it to be True?

Comment: `'menu_ask'.lower()` is simply the string `'menu_ask'`.  Get rid of those quotes.

Comment: I just ran your code, "--beer is in the menu" is True

Comment: just replace `'menu_ask'.lower()` by `menu_ask.lower()` . in other words delete the quotes of 'menu_ask'.

Comment: You could improve your menu. As it is, with jasonharper's fix (and Rafik's, and SuperKeksmann's), it shows you have sand, bee, and ink on the menu.

Comment: You should use a list or set instead of a string, so you won't match parts of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(menu_ask,"is in the menu = ", 'menu_ask'.lower() in menu.lower())
```

does not take the variable *menu_ask* but rather the string "menu_ask", which is not in *menu*

Change it to:

```
print(menu_ask,"is in the menu = ", menu_ask.lower() in menu.lower())
```

and it should work as intended